# cannot start tabler , node.js , ruby or jekyll error

Tags: node.js, ruby

I'm trying to start Tabler server on my local computer, have install everything as follows: [enter link description here][1]
but when I'm trying to start server, got an error, any suggestions where is the problem?

UPDATED:

I have reinstalled everything, but now I'm getting different error, with message,

```
    Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        22: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        21: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        20: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        18: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        17: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        16: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        15: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        14: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        13: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
        12: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
        11: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
        10: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:101:in `process'
         9: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:147:in `register_reload_hooks'
         8: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:147:in `require_relative'
         7: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/live_reload_reactor.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
         6: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/live_reload_reactor.rb:3:in `require'
         5: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.1/lib/em-websocket.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.1/lib/em-websocket.rb:3:in `require'
         3: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
         2: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `require'
         1: from C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/rubyeventmachine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tabler/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.6-x64-mingw32/lib/rubyeventmachine.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.5/rubyeventmachine (LoadError)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tabler-ui@0.0.32 jekyll-serve: `jekyll serve --livereload`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tabler-ui@0.0.32 jekyll-serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Akvile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-04T10_04_27_635Z-debug.log
ERROR: "jekyll-serve" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tabler-ui@0.0.32 serve: `gulp build && npm-run-all --parallel gulp-watch jekyll-serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tabler-ui@0.0.32 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Akvile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-04T10_04_27_931Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The error indicates a gem bundling issue; is there a  "bundle install" step somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when deploying tabler and this is how I fixed it :

1. Go to package.json file
2. Search for the following line : "jekyll-serve": "jekyll serve --livereload"
3. Change "jekyll serve --livereload" to "jekyll serve"

Hope this helps.